# Remove a given substring from | separated string

Tags: javascript, regex

Given an input string, I need to search within a pipe separated string and remove that input. Using "s1" as an example input:

- "s-0|s1" should be replaced with  "s-0"
- "ab|s1|s2" should be replaced with "ab|s2"
- "s1|s2" should be replaced with "s2"

For all those who are downvoting, I tried split without success. Maybe I overlooked something simple.

```
currentSelArr = inputString.split('|');  
    for(var i = 0; i < currentSelArr .length; i++) { 
         if(currentSelArr[i] === stringToDelete) {

           //What should I do here?
         }
      }
```

Comment: did you tried to use str.split('|') ?

Comment: yes. I was just trying to see if there's a way to do some form regex string manipulation.

Comment: Doing it with regex is tricky, because you have to handle the case where it's first, last, or in the middle differently. Split is much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way to do this is with string.split() rather than regex:

```js
"ab|s1|s2".split("|").filter(function(el, index) {
    return el !== 's1'; 
  }).join("|");
```

Comment: Just replace `return el.indexOf('s1') === -1;` with `return el.indexOf('s12') === -1; ` (or even use a variable in indexOf()).

Comment: I meant in the original string. "ab|s12|s2".

Comment: Ah. For exact match you can just do `return el !== 's1';` instead of `return el.indexOf('s1') === -1;`

Comment: Edited. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: this is not working for me.. newFilterParams = inputString.split('|').filter(el, index {
                 return el !== stringToDelete;            
               }).join('|');

Comment: What are the values of inputString and stringToDelete? What does newFilterParams return?

Comment: Also, you left out the function() declaration inside filter... take another look at the code I supplied.

Comment: Try `newFilterParams = inputString.split('|').filter(function (el, index) { return el !== stringToDelete; }).join('|'); `

Comment: No worries - happy to help!